# Need to update missing employee IDs in Active Directory by matching on Name in flat file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, provisioning

Recently completed an Azure AD provisioning integration between SuccessFactors and On-Prem AD.

In order for some of our existing users to get 'scoped in' to the Update provisioning, they first need to match on employee id (we currently do not use the Create functionality).

There are about 400 users that we've identified need to be matched, and our HR team has provided us with a csv with the following attributes (Full Name, EmployeeID).  I need to somehow compare this file with all users in AD who have no employee id, and if not, update EmployeeId with the contents from the HR provided file.

I'm a bit stuck on how to attack this.  Need a Big Brain :)

```
#import HR file with required attributes "Formal Name, EmployeeId"
#returns ~6500 entries
$SFUsers = Import-Csv Z:\ExportsFromProd\Global_ActiveHeadcountReport_08292022.csv

#returns ~1400 entries
#some accounts never get an employee id
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -Properties EmployeeID | Where-Object {$_.employeeID -eq $null}

foreach ($account in $users) {

    $accountName = $account.name
    get-aduser -Filter {Name -eq $accountName} -Properties * | Select-Object samaccountname, displayName

    #this is where i need help:

    <#
       try {
            Lookup $SFUser.'Formal Name' in $SFUsers array???
            Get $SFUser.'EmployeeID' | set-aduser $account -employeeId $SFUser.'EmployeeId'
            
        }
        catch {

        }
        finally {

        }
    #>
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the faster `-Filter` or `LDAPFilter` parameters of Get-ADUser to find only users where the EmployeeID property is unset.

Also, your code could be done by using Get-ADUser only once:

```
#import HR file with required attributes "Formal Name, EmployeeId"
#returns ~6500 entries
$SFUsers = Import-Csv -Path 'Z:\ExportsFromProd\Global_ActiveHeadcountReport_08292022.csv'

#returns ~1400 entries
#some accounts never get an employee id
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeid -notlike '*'" -Properties DisplayName, EmployeeID
# or use LDAPFilter
# $users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!employeeID=*)" -Properties DisplayName, EmployeeID

foreach ($account in $users) {
    # try and find this user in the csv file either by .Name or .DisplayName property
    $HRUser = $SFUsers | Where-Object { $_.'Formal Name' -eq $account.Name -or
                                        $_.'Formal Name' -eq $account.DisplayName}
    if ($HRUser) {
        $account | Set-ADUser -EmployeeID $HRUser.EmployeeId
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "AD user $($account.Name) not found in the CSV file.."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect. Also, thanks for the LDAP tip.  It did go much faster.

Comment: @bomgar Thanks for the nice feedback!Being new to the platform, may I point you to the [tour]. It's a quick read about SO and there you can see what is customary when an answer solves your problem so others may also benefit if they have a similar question.